# How to get specific wikipedia data?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, wikidata, wikipedia, rdf

I only want to use the link structure and articles’ content of Wikipedia. Therefore, I want to downlaod the dump that contains only the following details.

- articles content
- link structure (i.e. re-directed page, out-link categories, disambiguation pages etc.)

Is there any link where I can download them directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data dumps are at https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20181201/ (currently). Article content (source code) is in the pages-articles files (e.g. `enwiki-20181201-pages-articles.xml.bz2` is all pages in a single file, `enwiki-20181201-pages-articles1.xml-p10p30302.bz2` is page IDs 10 to 30302, `enwiki-20181201-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2` is a single file with many separate bz2 streams). If you need all pages you are probably better off with the single-file plain bz2 format. Note the data might be in the TB range after uncompressing.

Link information is available as SQL dumps from the same page (towards the end of the list, files with templatelinks, imagelinks, redirects etc. in the name). These are 1:1 dumps of the corresponding MediaWiki tables so see [DB schema information](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout) for details.

If you need the page content as HTML, your best bet is probably processing one of the [Kiwix dumps](https://wiki.kiwix.org/wiki/Content) (they are in [ZIM](http://www.openzim.org/wiki/ZIM_file_format)) which contain a stripped down version of article HTML.

Answer (score 2):

For the later (categories, pages,...) I recommend using the various dumps that are available from the Wikidata project. The dumps are available [at the Wikimedia dumps source](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/wikidatawiki/entities/). The RDF format is described pretty well in the [Wikidata RDF dump description](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format).

Use the [Wikidata Toolkit](https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit) to process it and get the specific information you want. Or import it into a triple store like [blazegraph](https://www.blazegraph.com/).

For the Wikipedia article content, there are dumps provided by certain mirror servers in different formats and chunks. A promising example is [this mirror](http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/wikimedia.org/dumps/enwiki/20181201/). Others can be found [at the Wikimedia XML dump project](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Mirroring_Wikimedia_project_XML_dumps)